# Android development spelling error for dimen

Tags: android

My code at dimens.xml is as follows.

```
<!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16.0dp</dimen> 
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16.0dp</dimen>
```

Here I get a spelling error saying that the spellings of dimen is wrong. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

That's just the spell checker.
Your code is correct.
If you want to get rid of it change the spell checker options in your IDE.

If you're using Android Studio go to File->Settings->Spelling.